Fortran parsing data values from a text line
I have following line in the middle of data:
Lattice="14.118460851 0.0 0.0 0.0 14.296182713 0.0 0.0 0.0 13.970592923" Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3:forces:R:3 energy=-1558.14096522 stress="0.01917032092545686 0.004679034697346147 -0.002715150092396106 0.004679034697346147 0.02270959988283459 -0.0033934086475967138 -0.002715150092396106 -0.0033934086475967138 0.02437748091748962" free_energy=-1558.0193295 pbc="T T T"

In this line, each keyword contains specific properties.
Here, I want to read this line and define some values to variable or array. I hope to read 9 real numbers after 'Lattice="' and store them as a, b, c, d, e, f, and I hope to read a single real number after 'energy=' and store it as g.
But I don't know how to write a Fortran script to read and recognize 'Lattice="' and 'energy=', and then select 9 or one next numbers.
How can I do this using Fortran?

If you have 9 (“nine”) numbers, how do you store them as a, b, c, d, e, f?

It may help to write the grammar in a form of a (E)BNF. Then you can even write subprograms or if branches based on the branches of the grammar. The first step of splitting then line into tokens is usually done separately before the actual parsing.

As with Steve's answer: a combination of index(), plus reading from an internal file (i.e from a character string). Whether it works will be a bit sensitive to how precise your input file is (right case; no spaces around '=' etc.) You might want to pre-process the string to ensure that.
It's possible that Fortran's newer stream IO might give an easier solution, but I haven't tried that.
subroutine getLatticeEnergy( str, L, E )
   use iso_fortran_env, only: real64
   implicit none
   character(len=*), intent(in) :: str
   real(real64), intent(out) :: L(9)
   real(real64), intent(out) :: E
   integer start, finish

   ! Find start of lattice components
   start = index( str, 'Lattice="') + 9
   finish = start + index( str(start:), '"' ) - 2
   read( str(start:finish), * ) L

   ! Find start of energy
   start = index( str, 'energy=') + 7
   read( str(start:), * ) E

end subroutine getLatticeEnergy

!=======================================================================

program test
   use iso_fortran_env, only: real64
   implicit none
   character(len=:), allocatable :: str
   real(real64) L(9)
   real(real64) E

   str = 'Lattice="14.118460851 0.0 0.0 0.0 14.296182713 0.0 0.0 0.0 13.970592923"'                     &
      // ' Properties=species:S:1:pos:R:3:forces:R:3 energy=-1558.14096522 stress="0.01917032092545686' &
      // ' 0.004679034697346147 -0.002715150092396106 0.004679034697346147 0.02270959988283459'         &
      // ' -0.0033934086475967138 -0.002715150092396106 -0.0033934086475967138 0.02437748091748962"'    &
      // ' free_energy=-1558.0193295 pbc="T T T"'

   call getLatticeEnergy( str, L, E )
   write( *, * ) "Lattice = ", L
   write( *, * ) "Energy = ", E

end program test

Output:
 Lattice =    14.118460851000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        14.296182713000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        13.970592923000000     
 Energy =   -1558.1409652200000    


You have a simple parsing problem. Although the form of the string is crying out for the use of a namelist.  Here's a program that shows you how to use Fortran's INDEX intrinsic subprogram.
program foo

   implicit none
   !
   ! buf must be large enough to hold the entire line.
   !   
   character(len=512) buf
   integer fd, i, j
   real a(9)
   !
   ! Assumes the text is in a file named 'a.txt'
   !
   open(newunit=fd,file='a.txt',status='old')
   read(fd,'(A)') buf
   close(fd)

   i = index(buf, 'Lattice="')
   if (i == 0) stop 'Lattice=" not found'
   !
   ! Add nine to location the first character after ".
   !
   i = i + 9

   j = index(buf(i:), '"') + i - 2  ! Subtract 2 to be in front of ".
   read(buf(i:j), *) a
   print *, a(1)
   
end program foo

